# Weak convergent $+$ strongly convergent subsequence $\Rightarrow$ strong convergence?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, limits-and-convergence, lebesgue-measure

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space containing functions defined over a bounded region $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$. Assume $f_n\in X$ converges weakly to $f\in X$, and also has a strongly convergent subsequence, say $f_{n_k}$, converging to $f$. Can we say that $f_n\to f$ strongly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(f_n)$ be any sequence which converges to $f$ weakly but not strongly. Define a new sequence $(g_k)$ by setting $g_{2n} = f_n$ and $g_{2n+1} = f$. Then $(g_k)$ shows that the answer to the question is negative.